# Mysql JOIN returns null for column that appears in both tables where it has no row to join

Tags: mysql, join

table A and B both have a column x

table A:

```
+----+----+
| id | x  |
+----+----+
|  1 | 1  |
+----+----+
|  2 | 2  |
+----+----+
```

table B:

```
+----+----+
| id | x  |
+----+----+
|  1 | 1  |
+----+----+
```

query:

```
SELECT A.* FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.x = B.x
```

result:

```
+----+-------+
| id | x     |
+----+-------+
|  1 | 1     |
+----+-------+
|  2 | null  |
+----+-------+
```

I want the null in the second result to be 2, since table A has x=2 for id=2.

I don't want to change to query to `SELECT A.x as y`, because that will require me to rewrite quite a bit of code, I would like to select it ***AS x***.

How can I do that?

(I tried `SELECT A.x as x` but that didn't help much)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: its hard to understand

Comment: Are you sure you're not selecting `B.*`?

Comment: You should probably break the habit of using `SELECT *` anyway. Be explicit about the filed you want and don't bother returning what you don't want.  The `LEFT JOIN` does what you want it to do in terms if giving result from A even if match doesn't exist in B, so I am not sure what your problem is.

Comment: Edited the question quite a bit to be more clear...

Comment: your query works look my demo

Comment: I think you want COALESCE(), as in COALESCE(b.x,a.x) x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just tried your query and it works fine though

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/336cd/1

Comment: darn, you're right. Sorry, seems the problem lies somewhere else in my actual query, as this over simplified example indeed works just fine. Well at least I know where to start debugging now. thanks for the effort

Comment: you welcome ! better that you try first and when you cant , then you can post question. :)

Comment: true, feel a bit stupid now ':)